# @online bibliography biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In my thesis, I need to have the webpage reference in the bibliography to look like this:

> [#]    Author (year). *Title*. Available:
>   http://www.uia.no/no/portaler/bibliotek/finn_fagstoff

I need the title to be italics and the "Available to say "Tilgjengelig"(norwegian)
Now it says "side" which means page. When I use @online, the reference is how I want it, exept the title is not italics, and it says "side"(page) instead of tilgjengelig(available)
I do not know how to upload files. I paste everything here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referanser.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Blablabla
\nocite{*}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Litteraturliste}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

This is my references:
My references:

```
@book{barbero2013,
address = {Boca raton, Florida},
author = {Barbero, Ever J},
booktitle = {Composite materials: Analysis and design},
keywords = {elementmetoden,komposittmaterialer,matematiske,modeller},
publisher = {CRC Press},
title = {{Finite element analysis of composite materials using Abaqus}},
year = {2013}
}
@book{bunsell2005,
address = {Bristol},
author = {Bunsell, A R and Renard, J},
keywords = {Fiberforsterkede komposittmaterialer,fiber,forsterkninger,kompositter,komposittmaterialer,materialer},
publisher = {Institute of Physics Publishing},
title = {{Fundamentals of fibre reinforced composite materials}},
year = {2005}
}
@misc{hovland2011,
author = {Hovland, G},
title = {{Mekatronikk Labfasiliteter}},
url = {http://old.uia.no/no/portaler/om\_universitetet/teknologi\_og\_realfag/-\_ingenioervitenskap/-\_-\_mekatronikk/lab},
year = {2011}
}
@online{byg402,
author = {{Universitetet i Agder}},
title = {{BYG402-G Elementmetoden i konstruksjoner}},
url = {http://old.uia.no/portaler/student/studierelatert/studiehaandbok/14-15/emner/byg402},
year = {2014}
}
@book{zenkert1996,
address = {Stockholm},
author = {Zenkert, D and Battley, M},
publisher = {Kungliga Tekniska h\"{o}gskolan},
title = {{Foundations of fibre composites}},
year = {1996}
}
@misc{iso3451,
title = {Plastics : Determination of ash. Part 1: General methods},
howpublished = {ISO3451-1},
year = {2008}
}
@misc{iso527,
title = {{Plastics - Determination of tensile properties - Part 5: Test conditions for unidirectional fibrereinforced plastic composites}},
howpublished = {ISO-527},
year = {2009}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a minimal working example always, not just fragments of code

Comment: Thanks. It is now edited. I posted the bib entry in a answer. I was not able to upload it to the question. I have not 10 "reputation".

Comment: @Ketil You can always edit your own questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with the `xpatch` package. I think the following corresponds to what you want for `online` entries:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{referanser.bib}
@online{Ibsen90,
author = {Henrik Ibsen},
title = {Hedda {G}abler},
year = {1890},
url = {http://www.uia.no/no/portaler/bibliotek/finn_fagstoff}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referanser.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{norsk}
{ bibliography = {Litteraturliste},
url = {Tilgjengelig},
  }


  \usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}{%
 \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
 \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
}{%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
 \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
}{}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}{%
 \newunit\newblock%
 \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
}{%
 \setunit{\adddot\space}\newblock%
 \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
}{}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}{%
\usebibmacro{finentry}}
{%
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was actually able to use only this:
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{norsk}
{ bibliography = {Litteraturliste},
url = {Tilgjengelig},
  }

Comment: @Ketil/ Do you mean the patches did not work?

Comment: One is supposed to replace a comma with a space (between author and year) the other to replace a comma with a dot (between title and ‘Tilgjengelig’ – as in your image.

Comment: Okay. I did not see that before now! Thanks! ;) It works fine.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the dot after the URL as well?

Comment: @Ketil: it *is* possible. See my updated answer. Not sure there are no side effects, however.

Comment: Do you mean another item in the bibliography, or some fields that are printed after the url in the same ‘online’ item?