# Biblatex \usepackage{xpatch}

Tags: biblatex, xpatch

In november i posted this question:
[@online bibliography biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214650/online-bibliography-biblatex)

The question was how to modify the bibliography to how i wanted it to look. I wanted the webpage reference to look like this:

> [#]    Author (year). *Title*. Available:
>   http://www.uia.no/no/portaler/bibliotek/finn_fagstoff

I got a good answer, but now I see that I get a dot after the URL, and I am not supposed to have that. Do you know how to "get rid of" the dot after the URL?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{referanser.bib}
@online{Ibsen90,
author = {Henrik Ibsen},
title = {Hedda {G}abler},
year = {1890},
url = {http://www.uia.no/no/portaler/bibliotek/finn_fagstoff}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referanser.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{norsk}
{ bibliography = {Litteraturliste},
url = {Tilgjengelig},
  }


  \usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}{%
 \setunit{\adddot\addspace}%
 \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
}{%
 \setunit{\addspace}%
 \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}%
}{}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}{%
 \newunit\newblock%
 \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
}{%
 \setunit{\adddot\space}\newblock%
 \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The dot is the `\finentrypunct`.  However, potentially some entries will print data after the url.  What do you want to see in those cases?

Comment: Also I think it should be `{Gabler}`  not `{G}abler`, using the later you may loose kerning, just as a test: `{V}oss` looses kerning.

Comment: The bibliography is just a test. What is the code I can write to remove the dot at the end? I do not want anything after the URL.

Comment: I see the older question has a modified answer that covers this new one, so I've marked as a dupe